# Datebase and php parent id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i'm working on this all day today and i'm actually really lost i have a table like this at the moment.

id | category | parent_id

id=5 category=Laptop parent_id=0 
id=7 category=Houses parent_id=0
id=8 category=HP parent_id=5
id=9 category=Lenovo parent_id=5

so what i'm trying to do is get this as a category sub category style something like;

- Laptop

  - HP
  - Lenovo
- Houses

until know what i have;

```
            <?php
        include_once("dir/db.php");
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0");
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
            ?>
                <a href="gallerycato.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><li><?php echo $row['category'] ?></li></a>

        <?php endwhile;?>
    </ul>
```

output;

```
<ul>
                            <a href="gallerycato.php?id=5"><li>Laptops</li></a>

                            <a href="gallerycato.php?id=7"><li>Houses</li></a>

                </ul>
```

but i'm trying to get my Lenovo and HP under Laptop i'd be really happy if you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Loop through the categories and within that loop run a query to find laptops `WHERE category = <current loop value>` and then loop through the laptops in the same category loop.

Comment: @Script47 any chance helping? i'd be really happy i'm looping the categories in what i have i think but i dont know how to continue after

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
        include_once("dir/db.php");
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0");
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
            echo "<a href=\"gallerycato.php?id=" . $row['id'] ."\"><li>" . $row['category'] . "</li></a>";

            $sub_result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = " . $row['id']);
            echo "<ul>";
            while($sub_row = $sub_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
               echo "<a href=\"gallerycato.php?id=" . $sub_row['id'] ."\"><li>" . $sub_row['category'] . "</li></a>";
            endwhile;
            echo "</ul>";
        endwhile;
        echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU YOU ARE BEST

Comment: My pleasure :)!